# How to reuse framebuffer texture in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, framebuffer, render-to-texture

is there a possibility to save the framebuffer to texture. So that i can reuse the framebuffer to create a new texture?

```
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture()
```

will return the same texture everytime.

Edit:

I calculate shadow and don't wanna recalculate the static lights. So i want to save the static lights / shadow calculation in a texture. Currently i have to make a new framebuffer for each light to save them. And thats inperformant.

Comment: Please give some more information. What exactly do you want to achieve? You write, that you want to reuse the same FrameBuffer as Texture. But then you write "will return the same texture everytime.". Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Added more informations. Is it understandable?

Comment: If you start/begin your FrameBuffer, render all lights and shadows, then end the FrameBuffer and call `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture()`, this should give you a `Texture` of your lightmap. Isn't that working?

Comment: Y it gives a texture but when i calculate the next light the previous will be overwirtten. The framebuffer only use one texture the whole time.

Comment: You write the whole lights/shadows into one framebuffer and then call `getColorBufferTexture()`. So you have a lightmap of all your lights. If the light changes you need to recalculate it, so also the Texture changes. So you just need to use 1 Texture for ALL lights.

Comment: then i need at least two buffers for dynamic and static lights? And i cant map the whole map in one texture.

Comment: Ah okay now i understand. Store 2 Textures. 1 for static, which you only write once and once for dynamic, which renders everytime.

Comment: Yop and i got much lights and a big map therfore i would store all lights in seperate Textures. But how?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48370/discussion-between-springrbua-and-kani)

Comment: unfortunately the link to the discussion chat is broken. Any update on this?

Comment: We had something but I think it was not a good solution, cause I changed the logic fully to calculate it in the shader.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the setupTexture method of the FrameBuffer class to provide a different texture object. Look at the default implementation of setupTexture in the libgdx code.